# When writing the conditions for the if statement, it doesn't generate the required text on the html page

Tags: javascript, html, conditional-statements

I am new to javascript. I'm trying to make a simple javascript game that allows the user to click the button to generate random numbers. If the number is 7 than the user wins. Problem is when writing the conditions for the if statement, it doesn't generate the required text on the html page. It should say "congrats you won" or "try again next time" but all it does is display the x value to the html page. It doesn't seem to recognize the conditions in the if statement... What am I doing wrong?

```js
function generateNum() {
  let x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  return x;


    let text = null;
    if (x == 7) {
    text = "Congrats you won!!!";
   }else {
    text = "Better luck next time...";
  }

document.getElementById('display_text').innerHTML = text; // NOTE: make sure the quotes match here and on html page.


}
```

```html
<html lang = "en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>JavaScript Basics -- FrontEnd</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Click the button to win lucky number 7!</p>
  <p align = center><button onclick="document.getElementById('display_text').innerHTML = generateNum()">PLAY</button></p>
  
<h2><p id='display_text'align = center></h2></p><br></br>
<h1><p id='show_number' align = center></p></h1><br></br>

  <!-- JavaScript should always be placed after the body tag 95% of the time. -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your second line in the JS function is `return`. That's ending the execution of the function. No code after that within the function is ever run.

Comment: Wow thanks! problem solved! I was stuck for days! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comment, your return in the function is what caused the bug. Here's also your code slightly cleaned up:

```js
function play() {
  var number = Math.ceil((Math.random() * 10));
  var text;
  if (number == 7) {
    text = "Congrats you won!!!";
  } else {
    text = "Better luck next time...";
  }
  document.getElementById("show_number").innerHTML = number;
  document.getElementById("display_text").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>JavaScript Basics -- FrontEnd</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Click the button to win lucky number 7!</p>
  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <button onclick="play()">PLAY</button>
    <h2 id="display_text"></h2>
    <h1 id="show_number"></h1>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you're returning `x` before your `if` conditions, and the `return` keyword exits from the function. Put this line

```
return x;
```

After this line:

```
document.getElementById('display_text').innerHTML = text;
```

And your code should work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You are **returning** `x` before if else statement.
`return` is used to finish the function by returning something. When you call return the function will stop at that time.
Here is an example:

```
function returnMyAge(age){
   console.log(age); // 20
   return age;
   console.log(`Again my age: ${age}`); 
   // nothing shows. bcz of this function finishes on return called.
}
returnMyAge(20)
```